# Do I really need to add "\n" to every PHP statement that I write in a script if I dont want my output to be like totally messed up?

Tags: php

I'm learning PHP and writing it and executing in the browser is cumbersome.
So I write it as a script and execute it on the terminal, such as

```
me@machine $ php script.php
```

However, it seems to me, all statements are printed to the same line, if not explicitly a newline character is also printed.

```
<?php
echo "Hello World.\n";
?>
```

If I omit `\n`, I end up with

```
me@machine $ php hello_world.php
Hello World. > me@machine $
```

which kind of is lame.

Do I really, like really really (as in "totally really"), need to type `\n` for every statement I like to test?

Comment: Use `error_log` instead to print to stderr, *with* a trailing newline.

Comment: if you like super totally really need to go to the new line because having it on there is like way super lame, then yes.

Comment: Yes, you need to. Most C-style languages require explicit control characters for this explicit result. You're however allowed to write your own function, say `writeLn()`, to add a newline implicitly.

Comment: @Avila, can you elaborate on the `error_log` approach?

Comment: why -1? Apparently, this topic does raise discussion.

Comment: I think this question has some potential if reworked a little bit.

Comment: @TMOTTM and what if you need output several things in a loop on the same line? Like this: `The first 10 quadratic numbers: 0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81`. You need a loop with an `echo` without newline!

Answer (score 1):

You've got a choice:

- Include a `\n` on the end, and have a line feed.
- Leave out the `\n` and don't have a line feed.

It's up to you. No, you don't *need* to have it there, but if you want to output text to the command line, you probably do want it.

I guess there's one other alternative. Since PHP outputs content that is outside of the `<?php .. ?>` tags as plain text, you could just put a blank line at the end of your code after the final `?>`. That will cause PHP to output a new line at the end without you needing to write `\n`.

But to be honest, putting the `\n` in your string is better coding practice. (And frankly, `\n` isn't exactly the worst thing in the world to having in your code. if you can't cope with the horrors of seeing `\n` in your code, then you're going to have a hard time reading most program code anyway... just wait to you learn Regex!!!)

Comment: They're different languages. They work differently. Someone more familiar with PHP may equally find Python's automatic linefeed uncomfortable. "I didn't ask for a linefeed, why have I got one?" Both languages have got a valid approach; they've gone in different directions, but they're both valid.

Comment: ok, i appreciate that. Still i was wondering (given all the PHP functionality), if there was a canonical way of getting a new line after each statement automatically.

Comment: No, no there isn't. I guess it's down to PHP's history as a web language that it's never been necessary (as well as its roots in Perl and C). Python is more familiar with the command line than PHP, so its natural for it to be more friendly toward that kind of usage.

Answer (score 1):

No. You might write your own writeLn() function and maybe use `PHP_EOL` instead of `\n`, depending on what the script is for. (New-line string differ across systems, and `PHP_EOL` is your *server's* version of new-line, so it makes your script portable at least in regard of the running environment.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use `\n` to print a new line.

PHP will only print that which you tell it to print. So, if you want a new line then you need to print a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements.

`\n` is representing a new line break.

So if you are testing a single command with a single echo, from command line you might beable to go without the newline break.

If you have multiple echos, all the output will be jumbled into one long text.

```
function NewLine ($Text)
{
  $Text = $Text."\n";
  return $Text;
}

echo NewLine('This Text Will Have A New Line Appended To The End');
```

Comment: i tried to make clear that I wish the command to arrive at a new line. I guess i failed..

Comment: @TMOTTM Not the best approach, but you could push the text through a function which will append a new line to the end.

Comment: You need to use double quotes. Single quotes do not expand `\n` to a new line character.